# Beta versions of build instruments for iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, app-store, app-store-connect

Whate I have to choose: building and publishing app in App Store with xCode 15 beta 6 and iOS 17 beta OR xCode 14.2 and iOS 16.4?

All my Testflight builds are made by xCde 14.2 and iOS 16.4, but I'd like to have most actual build possible.

Comment: You can’t publish Beta apps to the App Store until RC/GM version is out.